# Setting an attribute of a child <div> inside a cloned Node

Tags: javascript, clone, clonenode

I have cloned a node, but i want to set or change an attribute of a div inside that cloned node, specifically, change the `id` of `div id="test0"`

I can't find any documentation out there on this, any straight JavaScript guys out there know a solution?

```
var c = document.getElementById("stone-opt0"),
cloned = c.cloneNode(true);

//CODE THAT DOESN'T WORK
cloned.getElementById("test0").id = "new-id";
```

What I am doing is looping through a large list of items, and placing these items into a document fragment, which i then push to the page once... I am doing this rather than adding each element to the page, then modifying after attaching to the DOM (which would be faster, no?)

Comment: Why in the world would you tag your question as `jquery` and then say "No jQuery!"...

Comment: i did that to try and get more javascript people to view the question. i removed it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to call `getElementById` on the context of an element node. This is not possible: the `getElementById` method exists only on the `document` node (because `id` values have to be unique to the document). By contrast, you can do `getElementsByTagName` or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll) based on the context of an element.

You could, therefore, use the `querySelectorAll` method to do this, as long as you don't mind not supporting browsers that don't support this method, e.g. IE8.

```
cloned.querySelectorAll('[id="test0"]')[0].id = "new-id";
```

Comment: is there no way of doing some sort of childNode, like XML... something that would be supported cross-browser?

Comment: @JoelGrannas You could loop through all descendant elements and look for the ID. Alternatively, you could use a library that solves this kind of problem for you. jQuery springs to mind...

Comment: @JoelGrannas: `querySelectorAll` is going to work on nearly every browser except IE7 and earlier (http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector). While `getElementsByTagName` should work on every browser out there as far as I know.

Comment: thanks, i will try this now... im not worried about IE7, as i can push them to a legacy application

Comment: @JoelGrannas: Little known fact, jQuery actually uses `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsBYTagName`: 
https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L246
https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L1442
(though it does so with a good deal of cross-browser cleanup for corner cases, so I guess you're right that using jQuery would be a better solution than re-inventing that particular wheel).

Comment: @lonesomeday thanks, this worked for me 
(i had a class on the div as well) 

cloned.querySelectorAll('div.checkboxes')[0].id = "checkboxes" + step;

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `cloned.getElementById("test0").id = "new-id"` *after* you attach `cloned` to the DOM? `getElementById()` can be finicky if you're looking for something that's not part of the DOM. And when I say "finicky", I mean "generally flat out doesn't work."

You might try creating a hidden element (like a `<div style="display:none">`) on the page and attaching `cloned` to that so that it doesn't show up on the page until you're ready.

Comment: I did not try it that way... i know that would probably work, however, i am pushing this object into a documentFragment, then appending all at once.

Comment: Forget what I said, I think @lonesomeday has your answer. :-)

Comment: i read what you said... My thought was, because i am looping through a large list of items, that appending each to the dom, then modifying would be slower than taking all of the items, putting them into a doc fragment, then appending in one action.